# Buttons not changing to full when clicked apart from the final one

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want all the buttons to change to full when clicked, but I only got the last one to work. This is my code, but I can't get the others to work. Help would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable (0, 0)


def button():
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(5):


seat2=Button(root,text="empty",bg="green",fg="black",height=5,width=10)
            seat2['command']=lambda s1=seat1:(toggle_text(s1))
            seat2.grid(row=x, column=y)
button()



def toggle_text(s1):
    """toggle Button text between empty and Full"""
    if s1["text"]== "empty":
        #switch to Full
        s1["text"]= "Full"
```

Comment: This code can't run. You never define `seat1`, and the indentation is messed up.

Comment: how can i make it work?

Comment: first make correct indentions. On SO you can use button `{}` to correctly format code in question.

Comment: what is `seat1` ? why not `seat2` ?

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works. I haven't refactored the code to improve it but it seems to do what you expect.

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable (0, 0)

def toggle_text(s1):
    """toggle Button text between empty and Full"""
    if s1["text"] == "empty":
        #switch to Full
        s1["text"] = "Full"
    else:
        s1["text"] = 'empty'

def button():
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(5):
            seat2=Button(root,text="empty",bg="green",fg="black",height=5,width=10)
            seat2['command']=lambda x=seat2: toggle_text(x)
            seat2.grid(row=x, column=y)


button()
```